# Checking for null value

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am printing a URL in following manner:

```
 NSLog(@"url is %@",cacheManager.url);
```

The output of this is:

```
url is (null)
```

How should I check the URL in if condition so that a null URL should not be entered?

Comment: just use this - if (url == null) {}

Comment: if(cacheManager.url != nil) Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: `if([url isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check like

```
if(cacheManager.url.length == 0)
```

or

```
if(cacheManager.url == nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!cacheManager.url)
{
    // do something.
}
```

The above should work. You can also try..

```
if(![cacheManager.url isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    // do something.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *string = cacheManager.url;

if ((NSNull *)string == [NSNull null]){

}
```